# Force Maven 3 to copy 'provided' dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I use copy-dependencies goal to copy dependencies for current artifact.
But it doesn't copy dependencies with scope 'provided'.
How to fix it?

The xml configuration is standard:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <excludeArtifactIds>project-services</excludeArtifactIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>project-web</finalName>
</build>
```

Why do I want to do this?
Because I have to support both ant and maven builds working.
Therefore, I want to copy all dependencies into separate directory by running **mvn install -o**. In Ant build.xml I include path to that directory as classpath. After that Ant builds ear file and includes whole lib directory withoud system tools.jar and other 'provided' jars.
Version of Apache Maven is 3.0.3

Comment: Which Maven command are you running?

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Dependencies with scope=provided are marked that way because they are already present in the target environment. Why would you want to copy them?

Comment: Why mark them provided if you need to copy them?

Comment: I updated question. Maven 3.

Answer (score 1):

As documented by the plugin use includeScope:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#includeScope

**Edit**:

> Why do I want to do this? Because I have to support both ant and maven
>   builds working.

Consider to use Ivy to manage your dependencies with Ant:
http://ant.apache.org/ivy/

Here a post how you can configure Ivy to connect to Nexus:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21627528-how-do-i-configure-my-ivy-build-to-download-artifacts-from-nexus

Comment: But the documentation also says *Scope to include. An Empty string indicates all scopes (default).* So it shouldn't be necessary to use `includeScope`.

Comment: True, I've just seen that.